# How to create a custom Intellij template setter for use with Guava's Optional

Tags: java, android, templates, intellij-idea, guava

I am trying to write a custom setter using Intelij Template's but for Google's Guava Optionals. For example if I have a class as follows:

```
public class Note {
    public Optional<String> title;
}
```

Using the default `Setter` generation in Android Studio outputs:

```
public class Note {
    public Optional<String> title;

    public void setTitle(Optional<String> title) {
        this.title = title;
    } 
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
public class Note {
    public Optional<String> title;

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = Optional.fromNullable(title);
    } 
}
```

What I have tried so far is copying Intelij's Template and using `StringUtil.split()` to strip the `Optional<` part of the method signature. However I'm getting an error while I'm using the template below.

Error

```
Incorrect method 'public void setTitle($StringUtil.split($field.type, true, "<").get(1) title) { mTitle = title; }
```

Any advice on what I should do?

Default `Intelij Default` Template for Setter Generation

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

My custom Guava Optional Setter Generation

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($StringUtil.split($field.type, true, "<").get(1) $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what error exactly you receive?

Comment: @thst I've updated the post above. Specifically the method never gets generated and a red bubble with the following is displayed: `Incorrect method 'public void setTitle($StringUtil.split($field.type, true, "<").get(1) title) { mTitle = title; }`

Comment: Where did sou find $StringUtil? It is not documented afaics. You can use groovy code to accomplish String manipulation. But there is no sample for that.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't quite sure where I could find any documentation for String manipulation. I did a quick search of `jetbrain StringUtil capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention` and found this:
http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/8.0/jetbrains/buildServer/util/StringUtil.html ... there you can find the signature for `StringUtil.split()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I found that in [`StringUtils`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/12.0/com/intellij/openapi/util/text/StringUtil.java#StringUtil.tokenize%28java.util.StringTokenizer%29), `split()` had a different signature than as posted above.

I was able to write a complete solution to create a setter for Guava Optionals below. It is quite fragile as I am new to templates in IntelliJ, as it relies on the package name `com.google.common.base.Optional` and also on the [`StringsUtils`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/12.0/com/intellij/openapi/util/text/StringUtil.java#StringUtil.tokenize%28java.util.StringTokenizer%29) that doesn't seem to be documented officially.

It first checks if the `$paramName` is a wrapped `Optional`. If so, complete the setter with Guava optional setting. Otherwise, fallback to the default IntelliJ setter.

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
    static ##
#end
#if($StringUtil.split($field.type, "<").get(0).equals("com.google.common.base.Optional"))    
    #set($paramSignature = $StringUtil.trimEnd($StringUtil.substringAfter($field.type, "<"), ">"))
    #set($fieldAssignment = "Optional.fromNullable(" + $paramName + ")") 
#else
    #set($paramSignature = $field.type)
    #set($fieldAssignment = $paramName)
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($paramSignature $paramName) { 
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
        this.##
    #else
        $classname.##
    #end
#end
$field.name = $fieldAssignment;
}
```

**EDITED** Code based on feedback from @ChiefTwoPencils.

Comment: If nothing else, I'd suggest, if you don't follow my advice in the answer, that you rearrange the code to have less duplication since most of it is unnecessary.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Done. If there any other additional optimization please feel free to advise – thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I see your answer, and that's nice, but you must know you don't have to complicate the template with conditionals for each type you need (even though you only have one now; what about next time?).

Instead, why not create your own for this specific need and choose when you go to create the methods?

I'll be the first to admit this could be done a little nicer; I was just trying to see if I could get it to work right. Nonetheless, it's not dependent on the fully qualified package name of `Optional`; I don't even have Guava installed and it works.

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
void set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention(
  $StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier(
    $helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)
  )
)($StringUtil.trimEnd($StringUtil.substringAfter($field.type, "<"), ">") $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = Optional.fromNullable($paramName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getter, in my case I require first letter in capital letter and remove the 'm' of a field variable

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#if($field.recordComponent)
  ${field.name}##
#else
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'm'))
  #set($name = $name.substring(1, $name.length()))
#end
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  Is##
#else
  Get##
#end  
${name}##
#end
() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

For setter is the same, remove the 'm' of a field variable and the param also remove it and set lowercase first letter

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
#set($functionName = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($paramName, 'm'))
  #set($paramName = $paramName.substring(1,2).toLowerCase() + $paramName.substring(2, $paramName.length()))
  #set($functionName = $functionName.substring(1)) 
#end
void Set$functionName ($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```

Example:

```
private Handler mJobHandler;
```

Getter:

```
public Handler GetJobHandler()
{
    return mJobHandler;
}
```

Setter:

```
public void SetJobHandler(Handler jobHandler)
{
    mJobHandler = jobHandler;
}
```